# "CREATE SECURITY POLICY" unrecognized in OrientDB 3.2.27

Tags: orientdb, orientdb3.0

I'm running OrientDB 3.2.27 using the default Docker image and entering the CREATE SECURITY POLICY command at the console gives "!Unrecognized command: 'create security policy'" . The documentation suggests that it should exist, but I don't see it -- and the console interactive help doesn't know about it either. What gives?